# ¿Cómo crear un campo tipo date calculado en MySQL?

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

¿Cómo crear un nuevo campo a partir de una fecha que ya tengo?

```
SELECT fur FROM embarazadas
```

y de ese fpp también voy a calcular la fpp sumando 240 días. He intentado sumando días con adddate.

```
UPDATE embarazadas.embarazadas
SET fur = DATE_ADD(fur, INTERVAL 240 DAY)
WHERE idEmbarazada = 248
```

Answer (score 1):

Con esta query debería bastar

```
SELECT fur, DATE_ADD(fur, INTERVAL 240 DAY) AS fpp FROM embarazadas
```

Comment: perfecto man bro  me funciono perfecto esta query

Answer (score 0):

Formalmente no es necesario que guardes la `fpp` en otra columna porque violarías la 1ra forma normal. Es el mismo caso de los teléfonos (Es decir, sería redundante hacer una tabla con telefono1, telefono2, movil, etc).

Lo mejor es que hagas el calculo de la fpp, ya se que lo hagas por medio de la base de datos o por el lenguaje de programación que estés usando; siendo este ultimo preferible.

Si es por base de datos solo has un:

```
SELECT fur + 240 FROM embarazadas
```

y te devolvería la fpp.

Espero que te sirva. Saludos

Comment: si eso quiero calcular la fpp pero al sumar solo 240  me muestra lo datos 20160770 asi

Comment: por eso te recomiendo hacer el calculo no en la base de datos sino con el lenguaje de programación con que estés haciendo el sistema.